# Google Drive & iOS8 UIDocumentPickerViewController - file grayed out

Tags: ios, ios8, google-drive-api

I'm using iOS8 [UIDocumentPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentPickerViewController_Class/index.html) to export and import a zip file to different cloud services (iCloud,DropBox,Drive, etc.).

I don't have issues with iCloud and Dropbox, but with Google Drive I can't import the file because it is grayed out in the interface that displays files (export is working like a charm).

The funny thing is that if I upload a zip file to Drive via the Web interface, the file is not grayed out and I can import it via [UIDocumentPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentPickerViewController_Class/index.html) - so I suspect this is an issue during the export that create the issue when I want to import the zip file.

Notes:

The exported zip file can of course be downloaded via Google drive web interface.

I tried to use a proprietary extensions (instead of .zip) defined it the info.plist, but it is the same result (works everywhere except when importing from Drive)

I thought the issue was with the UTI passed to [UIDocumentPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentPickerViewController_Class/index.html) but I tried all kind of UTI (kUTTypeZipArchive, @"public.archive", @"public.zip-archive") with no success (in both case: with a proprietary extension, or with a .zip extension)

I also export/import XML files (with a proprietary extension) and everything is working well for all cloud services including Drive - I just had to add the "public.data" UTI in the allowed UTIs in [UIDocumentPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentPickerViewController_Class/index.html).

Comment: Did you ever end up resolving this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Nope - I think we need a Google Drive app update to fix that (perhaps there is already one by the way...)

Comment: If there is it was sometime in the last few days.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solution now?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in Google Drive. It does not handle the allowedUTIs correctly.

I also wanted to open my own proprietary types, but they didn't work. I had to add "public.data" to allow all files and check the extension when a document was picked. This is not as nice as if only my types were available in the picker, but it works.